# How to do a Diskpart Clean on OS X

Tags: hard-drive, osx-yosemite, diskpart

Is there a way to perform the equivalent of (Windows') [`diskpart clean`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) via MacOS X? I have to completely bomb some drives so that they can be formatted correctly in a buffalo Linkstation that I have.  However it's posing an issue as it's very picky about what's on the drives before it formats (something I was unaware of when I bought it).

Performing [`diskutil eraseDisk`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) is good and all, but it forces me to also select a filesystem and volume name.  `diskpart clean` on Windows doesn't do this, and produces a "clean" disk (with no volumes at all), which is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy-to-use, albeit slightly dangerous, method would be to simply overwrite the partition table:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX bs=1m count=2
```

... where `diskX` is the disk you want to nuke. Be careful because this command won’t ask.

This writes zeroes to the first 2 MiB, which should be sufficient to remove any and all partitioning schemes and whatnot.

*Update*: It might also be necessary to nuke the backup GPT table at the end of the disk:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX bs=1m seek=1907727
```

... with `1907727` being a value for a standard 2 TB consumer drive of I own, which has a total size of 2,000,398,934,016 bytes. I selected `2000398934016 / (1024 * 1024) - 2`, discarding any decimal places.

Both `count` and `seek` in the command lines above are multiples of the block size `bs` specified on the same command line.

Comment: This helped. They needed to be in a raw state for the box to write it's own mbar or whatever. Not 100% on the mechanics of it all but it's working now because of this.